# If else statement error in Python

Tags: python, regex, function, if-statement

I keep getting the error Invalid syntax on the first elif. I am pretty sure the syntax is right, but I have no clue why I keep getting this error.

```
def make_tracker(self):
        self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show system information\'',line)
        if self.region:
          self.region = "show system information"
          return self.region

        self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'',line)
        elif self.region:
          #The error is on the elif statement it self ^
          self.region = "CPM or IOM"
          return self.region

        self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show mda detail\'',line)
        elif self.region:
          self.region = "MDA"

        else:
          print"Could not Enter any of the regions"
```

Comment: Well, no, that syntax is not right. `elif` can only exist after an `if`; but you have that `self.region` before.

Comment: You can't have expressions between `if` and `elif` that aren't part of the `if` scope.

Comment: Since you use `return` after the first `if` and the first `elif`, you don't need `elif` at all. Replace them with `if`.

Comment: Note too that you don't need to use regex to search a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is what yuo want, replace the `elif` with `if`

```
def make_tracker(self):
    self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show system information\'',line)
    if self.region:
      self.region = "show system information"
      return self.region

    self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'',line)
    if self.region:
      #The error is on the elif statement it self ^
      self.region = "CPM or IOM"
      return self.region

    self.region = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show mda detail\'',line)
    if self.region:
      self.region = "MDA"
      return self.region

    print"Could not Enter any of the regions"
```

Now there is no need for an `else` statement, but you must add a `return` on the third `if`, otherwise the `print` at the end will be executed.

For more information about `if.. else ..` statement [read the tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, the problem is the expressions between your if and elif statements. to preserve the current functionality you could change the self region variables to something like

```
def make_tracker(self):
    self.regionSystem = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show system information\'',line)
    self.regionCard = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show card detail\'',line)
    self.regionMDA = re.search(r'CLI Command: \'show mda detail\'',line)

    if self.regionSystem:
      self.region = "show system information"
      return self.region

    elif self.regionCard:
      #The error is on the elif statement it self ^
      self.region = "CPM or IOM"
      return self.region

    elif self.regionMDA:
      self.region = "MDA"

    else:
      print"Could not Enter any of the regions"
```

Comment: yes, but note that if the first pattern is successful, you search the two last patterns for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with regexes at all, when working with literal strings?

```
def make_tracker(self):
    if "CLI Command: 'show system information'" in line:
        self.region = "show system information"
        return self.region

    elif "CLI Command: 'show card detail'" in line:
        self.region = "CPM or IOM"
        return self.region

    elif "CLI Command: 'show mda detail'" in line:
        self.region = "MDA"

    else:
        print"Could not Enter any of the regions"
```